# How do I prevent client applications from linking two different versions of my library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, swc

In AS3/Flex, there doesn't seem to be anything out of the box that prevents client applications from linking (either externally or "statically") two versions of my SWC. Historically, when this has happened, it has happened without any compiler warnings, and it's not until we observe anomalously "mixed" behavior in the final SWF that we know something's gone wrong. Is there anything I can do to strictly prevent two versions of my library from being included in an application?

Comment: i am not very familiar with AS3/Flex but isn't there a property you can extend and keep track of instances/references made to your application? i've done Singleton implementations in C# to prohibit a class from being instanced more than once, and if such attempt is made the memory address the class instance resides in is returned instead :)

Comment: It must be some symptom of the Flash VM or something in the Flex compiler but I've found that even static constants (or class definitions in the AS3 sense) being overridden get overridden silently.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this; but there is an order of precedence; so whichever SWC file is "included" last is the one that is used I believe.  Unless there are API changes between versions; I'm not sure why there would be compiler errors.  I would try to solve the by putting in place conventions / procedures for updating SWCs in builds.  @netSkay I'm pretty sure he is talking about 'linking' at compile time; so this wouldn't relate to keeping track of instances.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct ways of linking:

- static linking (when all the code of the program is known to the compiler at compilation time).
- dynamic linking (when code is loaded into a compiled application, but it was not necessarily compiled with the application that loaded it).

  1. You probably don't have to worry about, linking two different versions of the same code will most likely fail, unless the code is linked as data (as an embedded SWF rather then real code), in which case, whoever did that would probably know what they are doing.
  2. If you load different versions of the library, then several different things may happen. On one side of the matrix there is: "loaded into different security domains", "loaded into child security domain", "loaded into the same security domain", on another side of the matrix: "newer version loads older version", "older version loads newer version".

Now, every case of loading into different security domains may load different versions of your library, and there's nothing to do about it: that's what security domains are for. When loading into the same domain, the first loaded code wins. When loading into child domain, there will be two versions simultaneously in both domains.

What I would do:

```
class Version {

private static var version:String;

public static function setVersion():void {
    if (version) trace("Another library was loaded");
    else version = "1.0.0";
}}
import Version;
Version.setVersion();
```

The code outside the class definition will run as soon as the SWF is loaded. If this class has been loaded before, the `version` variable will be set. Obviously, you could use more sophisticated approach to figure out what to do and whether it is safe to move on, depending on what the versions are. Generally speaking, your code *should* support multiple versions in situations like "loading into child domain", it would be considered a bug, if it doesn't, or tries to circumvent it somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As soon as I get back to my development environment I will give this a shot!